# Can a PNG image contain multiple pages?

Tags: macos, png

On OSX I converted a multi-page PDF file to PNG and (somehow) it created a multi-page PNG file.

[image]

Is there an extension to the PNG format that allows this? Or is this not something I can validly create?

~~~~

To clarify, this is a PNG file, per the builtin `file` command and the `identify` command from imagemagick.

```
$ file algorithms-combined-print.png 
algorithms-combined-print.png: PNG image data, 1275 x 1650, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

$ identify algorithms-combined-print.png 
algorithms-combined-print.png PNG 1275x1650 1275x1650+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.537MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

And here is a pastebin of the command `identify -verbose algorithms-combined-print.png`: http://pastebin.com/hw1yuRKa

What is notable from that output is that the pixel count is `Number pixels: 2.104M` which corresponds to one page. However, the file size is 3.537MB, which is clearly sufficient to hold all the pages.

Per request, here is the output of `pngcheck`: http://pastebin.com/aCRMEd9L

Comment: Run "pngcheck -v algo-stroke.png" and show us the result.  You can get pngcheck from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson thanks for the advice, pastebin attached

Comment: Also, this is reproducible, so anyone with a Mac can try this at home.

Comment: You have `aCTL` and `fCTL` in the output of `pngcheck` - these are signs of APNG... http://stackoverflow.com/a/33432942/2836621

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PNG does not support "multipage" images.

[MNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/mng/) is a PNG variant that supports multiple images - mostly for animations, but it's not a real PNG image (diffent signature/header), and has never become popular.

[APNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) is a similar attempt, but more focused on animations - it's more popular and alive, though it's less official - it's also PNG compatible (a standard PNG viewer, unaware of APNG, will display it as a single PNG image).

Another possible explanation is that your image is actually a TIFF image with a wrong `.png` extension, and the viewer ignores it.

The only way to know for sure is to look inside the image file itself (at least to the first bytes)

Update: given the pngcheck output, it seems to be a APNG file.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have updated the post to show `file`, `imagemagick` and `pngcheck` all attesting that this is a PNG file.

Comment: APNG was designed to be able to hide inside a regular PNG. Applications such as ImageMagick that don't recognize APNG chunks will handle it as a regular single-image PNG and only show you the base image.

Comment: also it can be valid GIF