# Convert PixelReadSettings to MagickFormat in ImageMagick.Net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493671/merging-pdfs-and-converting-pdf-to-png-image-in-net-core-2-0)):

```
PixelReadSettings pixelReadSettings = new PixelReadSettings(width, height, StorageType.Char, PixelMapping.RGBA);
//this
                        using (MagickImage imgPdfOverlay = new MagickImage(rawBytes, pixelReadSettings))
                        {
                            imgBackdrop = new MagickImage(backdropColor, width, height);
                            imgBackdrop.Composite(imgPdfOverlay, CompositeOperator.Over);
                        }
```

I can't pass pixelReadSettings to new MagicImage - it expects MagicFormat. How to convert pixelReadSettings to MagicFormat?